# How to change different highlight Color of xAxis and yAxis in LineChartView in Charts for selected chartDataSet?

Tags: ios, swift, charts, linechart

Currently I am using this chart library [Danielgindi Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts).

What i am trying to achieve is, to change the highlight color of the lineChartView, could you please help me how to achieve the same.

Currently i am using this piece of code for changing the highlight color in the chart but unable to change the color of xAxis and yAxis for the selected chartDataEntry.

```
    let set1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: self.dataEntry, label: "chart")
    set1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    set1.mode = .horizontalBezier

    set1.drawVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled = true
    set1.highlightLineDashLengths = [8.0, 4.0]
    set1.highlightColor = UIColor.blue
    set1.highlightLineWidth = 2.0

    let data = LineChartData(dataSet: set1)
    self.chartView.data = data
```

Please find the attached image for the same.

[image: The required result where vertical highlight color is blue and horizontal highlight color is green]

So, how to change the color of vertical and horizontal color.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code worked for me.

Search this class and replace the code by this one.

```
import Foundation
import CoreGraphics

 @objc(LineScatterCandleRadarChartRenderer)
 open class LineScatterCandleRadarRenderer: BarLineScatterCandleBubbleRenderer
{
public override init(animator: Animator, viewPortHandler: ViewPortHandler)
{
    super.init(animator: animator, viewPortHandler: viewPortHandler)
}

/// Draws vertical & horizontal highlight-lines if enabled.
/// :param: context
/// :param: points
/// :param: horizontal
/// :param: vertical
@objc open func drawHighlightLines(context: CGContext, point: CGPoint, set: ILineScatterCandleRadarChartDataSet)
{

    // draw vertical highlight lines
    if set.isVerticalHighlightIndicatorEnabled
    {
        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: viewPortHandler.contentTop))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: point.x, y: viewPortHandler.contentBottom))
        context.strokePath()
    }

    // draw horizontal highlight lines
    if set.isHorizontalHighlightIndicatorEnabled
    {
        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: viewPortHandler.contentLeft, y: point.y))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: viewPortHandler.contentRight, y: point.y))


        context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.brown.cgColor)
        context.setFillColor(UIColor.orange.cgColor)
        context.strokePath()
    }
  }
}
```

So , basically this piece of code works for me in drawHighlightLines function.

```
 context.setStrokeColor(UIColor.brown.cgColor)
 context.setFillColor(UIColor.orange.cgColor)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
chart.xAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.red
chart.rightAxis.axisLineColor = UIColor.black
```